# Moving files from one folder to another using access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to move an excel file from one folder to another.

I have been modifying the code but only getting it to partially work.

**My Code:**

```
Name "C:\Excel\ID.xlsm" As "C:\Archive\ " & AuditID & ".xlsm"
```

**Whats Happening:**

When I run this code I get a debug saying: Path/File access error. Once its debugged, if I press 'play' again it successfully moves the file to the new path and renames it correctly.

So I am a little confused as to why I get the error message in the first place.

**I have also Tried:**

```
Name "C:\Excel\ID.xlsm" As "C:\Archive\ '" & AuditID & "'.xlsm"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Name "C:\Excel\ID.xlsm" As "C:\Archive\" & AuditID & ".xlsm"
```

I removed space after last `\`